# Is there a way to display content of several checklist selections in one output with Dash / Plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, radio-button, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I try to build a dashboard, that allows the user to check different checkboxes, which I figured out how to do. What I am struggling with, is how to combine the output into one line at the bottom of the page (instead of individual outputs, right under checkbox selection).

I found "state" and "caching" as a possible solution however I don't know what to do next.

Thanks for your help.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import time

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



app.layout = html.Div(children=[


    dcc.Checklist(id='my-checklist1',
    options=[
        {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
        {'label': 'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
        {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
    ],
    value=['MTL', 'SF']
    ),
    html.Div(id='my-div-checklist1'),
    html.Hr(),



    dcc.Checklist(id='my-checklist2',
    options=[
        {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
        {'label': 'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
        {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
    ],
    value=['MTL', 'SF'],
    labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
    ),
    html.Div(id='my-div-checklist2'),
    html.Hr(),


])



@app.callback(Output('my-div-checklist1', 'children'),
              [Input('my-checklist1', 'value')])
def prepare_data(categ):
    if categ:
        return html.Div([dcc.Markdown(
                         '''Output for {}'''.format(categ))])


@app.callback(Output('my-div-checklist2', 'children'),
              [Input('my-checklist2', 'value')])
def prepare_data(categ):
    if categ:
        return html.Div([dcc.Markdown(
                         '''Output for {}'''.format(categ))])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

If I select all boxes I get:

Output for 'MTL', 'SF', 'NYC' under the first section and
Output for 'MTL', 'SF', 'NYC' under the second section.

What I want is:
Output for 'MTL', 'SF', 'NYC', 'MTL', 'SF', 'NYC'

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly there is no need for caching. Your callbacks can have several inputs. You have to put both of your checkboxes into the decorator and adjust your function head:

```
@app.callback(Output('my-div-checklist2', 'children'),
              [Input('my-checklist1', 'value'),
               Input('my-checklist2', 'value')])
def prepare_data(categ1, categ2):
```

It is by the way also possible to have several outputs!

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was looking for. Works now.